# springboot does not connect to localhost:8080 as expect?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am newbie with java web and trying to make a very simple java website by spring boot as this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bq0j8ha410U

But, my problem is, when I ran the application, it did not tell me that "Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path" as the tutorial said, but nothing, as you can see in this picture [Picture about the problem Tomcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo33L.png)

So, when I tried to connect to localhost:8080 at broswer, it said to me that "This site can’t be reached" ofcourse.

By the way, I had many error when I ran it , the server said to me that "Could not create the view: org.eclipse.wst.server.ui.ServersView" and the Data Source Explorer said that "Could not create the view: org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DataSourceExplorerNavigator" ?

Here is my pom.xml, sorry because I do not know how to make it easily to see

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0       https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <relativePath />
      <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   <groupId>net.codejava</groupId>
   <artifactId>SpringBootWebApp</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <name>SpringBootWebApp</name>
   <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
   <properties>
      <java.version>16</java.version>
   </properties>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
   <repositories>
      <repository>
         <id>spring-milestones</id>
         <name>Spring Milestones</name>
         <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
         <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
         </snapshots>
      </repository>
      <repository>
         <id>spring-snapshots</id>
         <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
         <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
         <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
         </releases>
      </repository>
   </repositories>
   <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
         <id>spring-milestones</id>
         <name>Spring Milestones</name>
         <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
         <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
         </snapshots>
      </pluginRepository>
      <pluginRepository>
         <id>spring-snapshots</id>
         <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
         <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
         <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
         </releases>
      </pluginRepository>
   </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

Could you please give me some ideas ? Thank you very much for you time.

Comment: Can you add the pom.xml

Comment: Can you add full error trace. Your application didn't start right.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe web starter dependency is missing can you try with web dependency in your pom.xml(maven build file)

```xml
<dependency>  
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>   
</dependency>
```

Comment: Indeed, looking at the video spring-boot-starter-web is in the list of dependencies after the project is generated. That's the problem with videos, blink and you miss it.

Comment: This wont work in Intellij. Spring boot wont respond